# Facebook php script doesn't work online

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

I have a FB script and it works fine locally but it doens't online.
The first script is een script for the events and the second one is to get de Facebook albums.

```
<?php
        $fb_page_id = "408403535882715";
        $access_token = "Acces_token";

        $year_range = 10;

        $since_date = date('Y-01-01', strtotime('-' . $year_range . ' years'));
        $until_date = date('Y-01-01', strtotime('+' . $year_range . ' years'));

        // unix timestamp years
        $since_unix_timestamp = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
        $until_unix_timestamp = strtotime($until_date);

        $fields="id,name,description,location,venue,timezone,start_time,cover";

        $json_link = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_page_id}/events/feed/?fields={$fields}&access_token={$access_token}&since={$since_unix_timestamp}&until={$until_unix_timestamp}";

        $json = file_get_contents($json_link);

        $obj = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

        // count the number of events
        $event_count = count($obj['data']);

        for($x=0; $x<$event_count; $x++){
            if($x<1) {
                $start_date = date( 'l, F d, Y', strtotime($obj['data'][$x]['start_time']));

                $start_time = date('H:i', strtotime($obj['data'][$x]['start_time']) - 60 * 60 * 23);

                $pic_big = isset($obj['data'][$x]['cover']['source']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['cover']['source'] : "https://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_page_id}/picture?type=large";

                $eid = $obj['data'][$x]['id'];
                $name = $obj['data'][$x]['name'];
                $location = isset($obj['data'][$x]['location']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['location'] : "";
                $description = isset($obj['data'][$x]['description']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['description'] : "";

                echo "<div class='eventFrontpage'";
                    echo "<div class='info'>";
                        echo "<h1>{$name}</h1>";

                        echo "<span class='datum'>{$start_date} om {$start_time} uur</span></br>";

                        echo "<span class='locatie'>Locatie: {$location}</span></br>";

                        echo "<span class='content'>Info: {$description}</span></br>";

                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
                break;
            }
        }
        ?>
```

and this one (on different pages)

```
<?php
        $fb_page_id = "408403535882715";

        $json_link = "http://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_page_id}/albums?fields=id,name,description,link,cover_photo,count";
        $json = file_get_contents($json_link);

        $obj = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

        $album_count = count($obj['data']);

        for($x=0; $x<$album_count; $x++){

            $id = $obj['data'][$x]['id'];
            $name = $obj['data'][$x]['name'];
            $description = $obj['data'][$x]['description'];
            $link = $obj['data'][$x]['link'];
            $cover_photo = $obj['data'][$x]['cover_photo'];
            $count = $obj['data'][$x]['count'];

            // if you want to exclude an album, just add the name on the if statement
            if(
                $name!="Profile Pictures" &&
                $name!="Cover Photos" &&
                $name!="Timeline Photos" &&
                $name!="Mobile Uploads"
            ){

                $show_pictures_link = "photos.php?album_id={$id}&album_name={$name}";

                echo "<a class='mediaAlbum {$name}' href='{$link}' target='_blank'>";
                    echo "<img class='img-responsive' src='http://graph.facebook.com/{$cover_photo}/picture' alt=''>";
                    echo "<h2>{$name}</h2>";
                echo "</a>";
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Someone an idea?

Comment: Any error messages or anything?  Does your app within Facebook have the correct permissions for your server?

Comment: A see some errors but was on Friday and i fixed them, which permissions do you mean? to call te api you dont have to set permissions right? I have set the site url, set it to publish and connected the page to the app.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant, you've set your domain.

Comment: @JayBhatt the url_fopen = one (http://veurgekenonwies.nl/lala.php)
so that could not make the problem right? Do you have to set some other permissions or something?

Comment: Ok, i fixed it! Because it is php <5.4 i needed a line for translation: $obj = json_decode(preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $json), true);

Comment: Oh good, please post the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Because it was PHP < 5.4 on my server de code needed a translation :

```
$obj = json_decode(preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $json), true);
```